# ExtJS 4 Grid Row editing help

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

can anyone please point to a working example or provide a piece of code regarding row editing and how to submit the edited data to the server? I've implemented the add and delete records functionality in my grid, but I just can't get edit to work. In ExtJS3, I used to implement a button for editing, so the user clicked on a row and then on the button and a form with all the data from that record was loaded, providing the ability to edit the data and then save it. Since, for reasons unknown to me, I cannot get this to work in ExtJS4 (getSelection() and selModel.selected.items won't load the record into my form), I am forced to use inline editing.

I've been working for days now on this one without success. I understand that I need to implement an afteredit listener but can someone be so kind to show me a way how to pass the data from the editor to a PHP script so that I may manipulate the database from there?

Thanks

Comment: **Related Question:** [Fire “afteredit” after edit the entire row in ExtJS grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648208/fire-afteredit-after-edit-the-entire-row-in-extjs-grid) -- **Example:** http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/cell-editing.html

Answer (score 1):

these may help:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131482-Ext.ux.grid.plugin.RowEditing-add-some-usefull-features

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133477-Ext.ux.form.field.FormPanelEditor-for-ExtJS-4.0

Answer (score 0):

the shortest thing to do after having edited is

```
"store.sync();"
```

in store you have to give in api object the server side method to update the grid record:

```
"api:{
```

submit:'controllername.methodname'
}"

Make it in edit event from rowEditing plugin(button update).